# 3 relationships within each others for subscription

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4, relationship

I have hashtags and users can subscribe them. here is what I did for subscription:

```
function hashtag(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Hashtag');
}
```

And also there is user relationship in Subscription Model:

```
function user(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
}
```

The `user` Model has `subscribes` which is supposed to give me the hashtags that the Authed user subscribes. Here it is:

```
function subscribes(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Subscription');
}
```

Now with this code I tried to access the `hashtag`s the `Auth`ed user `subscribes` here is the view code:

```
@foreach(Auth::user()->subscribes->hashtag as $tags)
    {{ $tags->name }}
@endforeach
```

What I think is that, laravel expects a relationship table here, called `hashtag_subscription` or something like that. Now I got a bit confused with these relationships. I highy prefer to get around this withput creating extra table, I feel like I can accomplish it without an extra table.

Tables are as following:`user`, `hashtag`, `subscription`

Models: `Hashtag`, `Subscription`, `User`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your relationships first, because as I understood you one `Subscription` model has `One-To-One` relationship to both `User` and `Hashtag`:

```
function hashtag() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Hashtag');
}

function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

Then you can loop through user subscriptions and have access to both `Hashtag` and user to whom the initial user is subscribed to:

```
@foreach(Auth::user()->subscribes as $subs)
    {{ $subs->user->firstname }}
    {{ $subs->hashtag->name }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: I tried that, it expects. Table called hashtag_subscription. But in my opinion there is no need to that.

Comment: One subscription can have one hashtag?

Comment: That is right. Think of it as youtube channels subscription. One user subscribes a channel. The subscription is one to one right?

Comment: I guess I had to put belongsTo instead of belongsToMany right?